# Not able to register in ejabberd from a non-local ip

Tags: ejabberd

The ejabberd server in on LAN host on the 192.168.7.5 IP.
At the computer facing the Internet, the firewall redirects ports `5222, 5269, 5443, 5280, 3478, 5349, 49152:65535` to the *ejabberd* server.

I've read about [spam in creating accounts](https://www.process-one.net/blog/preventing_spammers_from-abusing_in-band_registration_in_ejabberd/), but I'm unsure about what to choose.
Thought of having `trusted_network: loopback`  but allowing registration from all IPs (later will be restricted at the firewall basis) using a *captcha* service.

When trying to register from *Gajim*, the process seems to keep trying forever.
At the ejabberd's logs:

```
2021-07-27 16:53:42.970 [info] <0.383.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:273 (<0.581.0>) Accepted connection 11.12.13.14:51267 -> 192.168.7.5:5222
```

Here's my `ejabberd.yml`:

```
hosts:
  - "example.cyou"
captcha_cmd: "/usr/local/bin/captcha.sh"
captcha_url: "http://example.cyou:5280/captcha"
captcha_limit: 20
loglevel: 4
certfiles:
  - "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/example.pem"
  - "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/example.cyou.key"
listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    tls: true
    starttls: true
    starttls_required: true
    protocol_options:
        - "no_sslv2"
        - "no_sslv3"
        - "no_tlsv1"
        - "no_tlsv1_1"
        - "no_tlsv1_3"
    ciphers: "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
    dhfile:
      "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/c2s_dh2048.pem"
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
    dhfile:
      "/usr/local/etc/ejabberd/certs/s2s_dh2048.pem"
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: ejabberd_http
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    register: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    turn_min_port: 49152
    turn_max_port: 65535
    turn_ipv4_address: 22.33.44.55
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "192.168.7.5"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
  -
    port: 5349
    transport: tcp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    tls: true
    turn_min_port: 49152
    turn_max_port: 65535
    ip: 192.168.7.5
    turn_ipv4_address: 22.33.44.55
s2s_use_starttls: optional
acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
  admin:
      user:
          - "admin@example.cyou"
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: all
  register:
    - allow: all
api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: loopback
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number
shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000
shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast
modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    docroot: "/var/spool/ejabberd/upload"
    put_url: "https://upload.@HOST@:5443"
    max_size: 10000000  #10MB
    file_mode: "0644"
    dir_mode: "0744"
    thumbnail: false
    access: local
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ip_access: all
    captcha_protected: true
    password_strength: 0
    registration_watchers:
      -
        "admin@example.cyou"
    access_from: register_from
    access: register
    welcome_message:
      subject: "Welcome!"
      body: |-
        Hi.
        Welcome to this XMPP server.
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: 
    credentials_lifetime: 12h
    services:
      -
        host: 192.168.7.5
        port: 3478
        type: stun
        transport: udp
        restricted: false
      -
        host: 192.168.7.5
        port: 3478
        type: turn
        transport: udp
        restricted: true
      -
        host: example.cyou
        port: 5349
        type: stuns
        transport: tcp
        restricted: false
      -
        host: example.cyou
        port: 5349
        type: turns
        transport: tcp
        restricted: true
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

Besides this, for the reverse proxy (nginx)

```
server {
        listen       5280 ;
        server_name  example.cyou;
        root /usr/local/www/nginx/example.cyou;
        index  captcha.html;

        location /captcha {
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
               proxy_pass http://192.168.7.5:5280;
        }
    }
```

So my questions are:

1. How can the config be corrected
2. If ejabberd is serving more than one host, how can different options be placed in `mod_register`, according to the host being serviced by ejabberd, for example, for example.cyou having the options as stated, but for host foobar.org having register open only for a local network and having the `registration_watchers` specified according to each of the hosts.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. If ejabberd is serving more than one host, how can different options be placed in mod_register, according to the host being serviced by ejabberd, for example, for example.cyou having the options as stated, but for host foobar.org having register open only for a local network and having the registration_watchers specified according to each of the hosts.

Use append_host_config. There's an example in
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/basic/#virtual-hosting that configures mod_muc differently for each vhost.